# HI mass from HI column density

Tags: radio

I have a galaxy for which I have HI column density values. I want to estimate the corresponding HI mass. To do the same, I want to estimate the flux density of this source. How can I achieve the same?

The equation to estimate the HI mass from HI flux density:

$$M_\mathrm{HI}=2.36×10^5D^2\textstyle\int F\,\mathrm{d}V \ M_\odot$$

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do you think to get F out of the integral?

Comment: You *have* a galaxy? :)